# Dúvida de como utilizar o hover

Tags: html, css

Queria quando eu colocasse o mouse em cima da `div.caixa` alterasse minha `div.caixa-titulo`, porém não consegui.

Meu código:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
    <!-- Meta tags Obrigatórias -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Pagina inicial</title>

    <style type="text/css">
      .caixa, .caixa-titulo, .caixa-conteudo{
        border-radius: 4px;
      }

      .caixa{
        border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
      }

      .caixa-titulo{
        padding: 10px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .caixa-titulo:hover{
        background-color: pink;
      }

      .caixa:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
      }
      </style>

  </head>
  <body>

    <section style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;">
      <div class="caixa">
          <div class="caixa-titulo">
              <h1>Calendário</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="caixa-conteudo">
            <p>
              Aqui está um calendário simples que você pode adicionar atividade nele, clique <a href="">Aqui</a>
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </section>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você deve colocar o `:hover` na classe da caixa `.caixa` para alterar a classe filha `.caixa-titulo`:

```
       evento
         ↓
.caixa:hover .caixa-titulo{
   ↑               ↑
  pai            filha
```

**Veja:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
    <!-- Meta tags Obrigatórias -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Pagina inicial</title>

    <style type="text/css">
      .caixa, .caixa-titulo, .caixa-conteudo{
        border-radius: 4px;
      }

      .caixa{
        border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
      }

      .caixa-titulo{
        padding: 10px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .caixa:hover .caixa-titulo{
        background-color: pink;
      }

      .caixa:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
      }
      </style>

  </head>
  <body>

    <section style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;">
      <div class="caixa">
          <div class="caixa-titulo">
              <h1>Calendário</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="caixa-conteudo">
            <p>
              Aqui está um calendário simples que você pode adicionar atividade nele, clique <a href="">Aqui</a>
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </section>


  </body>
</html>
```